# Move emails from one folder to another

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to move all the email message to another folder, its working fine however I want it to be done faster. Time consumed is more than one minutes, it should perform the tas within one minutes. Here is the code I tried

```
function tkldm() 
{ 
var shruntime = ss.getSheetByName("Test1"); 
var oldlab = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Test"); 
var Newlab = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Misc");  
var threads = oldlab.getThreads();  
var ThreadCountoldlabel = threads.length;   
var rntimelrow = shruntime.getLastRow(); 
var d = new Date(); 
var timeStamp = d.toTimeString();
shruntime.getRange(rntimelrow+1, 1).setValue(timeStamp);    
for ( var it = 0; it < ThreadCountoldlabel; it++)
{
threads[it].addLabel(Newlab).removeLabel(oldlab).refresh(); 
}  
var d = new Date();
var timeStamp = d.toTimeString();  
shruntime.getRange(rntimelrow+1, 2).setValue(timeStamp);  
}
```